# How do I get the cursor to only select the word in the h1 element and also add a line behind a word?

Tags: html, css, cursor

If I hover the cursor to the far left or right of the word "facebook" in the `h1` it still shows, but I only want it to show when the mouse is hovered on top of the word "facebook".

Also, can you tell me how to get horizontal lines next to the words "or". This is what I'm trying to duplicate for practicing coding https://m.facebook.com/login/?refid=8:

[image: https://m.facebook.com/login/?refid=8]

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.fb {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 20.5px;
    color:#1877F2;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top:10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.input {
    
    
}

.enter {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: flex;
    padding:12px;
    margin-bottom: -15px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 410px;
    background-color:#f7f7f8;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    filter: drop-shadow(0.5px 0px 0px lightgray)
}

.login {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    padding:10px;
    margin-bottom: -15px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    width: 410px;
    background-color:#1877F2;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.or {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 24px;
}

.click {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    padding:10px;
    margin-bottom: -15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 160px;
    background-color:#00A400;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor:pointer;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Facebook</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='style.css'/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="fb">facebook</h1>
    <Form>
        <div class="input">
        <input class="enter" type="text" id="emph" name="emph" placeholder="Mobile number or email address" required>
        <input class="enter" type="password" id='password' name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    </div>
        <button class="login" type="login">Log in</button>
        <span class="or">or</span>
        <button class="click" type="click">Create New Account</button>
        <p>Forgotten password?</p>
    </Form>
    <div class="left">
        <span>English(UK)</span>
        <br>
        <span>Espanol</span>
        <br>
        <span>Italiano</span>
        <br>
        <span>Deutsch</span>
    </div>    
    <div class="right">
        <span>Polski</span>
        <br>
        <span>Francais (France)</span>
        <br>
        <span>Portugues (Brasil)</span>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for including the code here that shows the problem, but it is better when you create a [MRE] with just the code related to the problem itself. This makes your question more useful to other users in future and easier for us to help with.

Answer (score 0):

It **is** selecting the `h1` BUT the `h1` is 100% wide...which is the default for a block level element. Make it `inline-block/flex` and center it some other way.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

.right,
.left,
.password {
  text-align: left;
}

.fb {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20.5px;
  color: #1877F2;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.input {}

.enter {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 410px;
  background-color: #f7f7f8;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  filter: drop-shadow(0.5px 0px 0px lightgray)
}

.login {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 410px;
  background-color: #1877F2;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.or {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 24px;
}

.click {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #00A400;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.or {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.or:before,
.or:after {
  content: "-----";
  margin: 0 .5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Facebook</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href='style.css' />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="fb">facebook</h1>
  <Form>
    <div class="input">
      <input class="enter" type="text" id="emph" name="emph" placeholder="Mobile number or email address" required>
      <input class="enter" type="password" id='password' name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    </div>
    <button class="login" type="login">Log in</button>
    <span class="or">or</span>
    <button class="click" type="click">Create New Account</button>
    <p class="password">Forgotten password?</p>
  </Form>
  <div class="left">
    <span>English(UK)</span>
    <br>
    <span>Espanol</span>
    <br>
    <span>Italiano</span>
    <br>
    <span>Deutsch</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <span>Polski</span>
    <br>
    <span>Francais (France)</span>
    <br>
    <span>Portugues (Brasil)</span>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

For bonus points I've added an option for the lines on either side of the `or`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with just a few changes to those elements, I've explained what to do below and given a full working example.

**1. Changing the cursor on hovering the word "facebook" only**

The `h1` element is a block element, so it takes up the full width by default. To only apply CSS to the word(s) in the header, you just need to put an `inline` element (e.g. span) around just the word itself so that the element only takes up the width of the word and we can target this element in the CSS:

```
<h1 class="fb"><span>facebook</span></h1>
```

Now all you have to do it apply the `cursor: pointer;` CSS to this element:

```
.fb span{  cursor: pointer; }
```

**2. Adding the horizontal line behind the word "or"**

We can do this using a background gradient. First we make `or` a block element to contain the line and fill the width we need, and add a span element around the word itself so we can treat it differently:

```
<div class="or"><span>or</span></div>
```

Now in our CSS we add the background gradient to the block-level element to create the line and adjust your other CSS like this (see comments for explanation):

```
.or {
    margin: 24px auto;        /* center the element horizontally */
    text-align: center;       /* center its content - i.e. the word "or" */
    width: 410px;             /* match the width set on the other elements */
    /* this creates the horizontal line across the centre of the div: */
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 48%, rgba(204, 204, 204, 1) 48%, rgba(204, 204, 204, 1) 52%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 52%);
}
```

This works fine, except we can see the line cutting through the word "or". This CSS will add a white background to just the word so that the line is not visible behind it.

```
.or span{
    background: #FFF;        /* hide the line in the background */
    padding: 0 10px;         /* add space either side so the line doesn't jut up against the word */
}
```

**Working Example putting all this together:**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.fb {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20.5px;
  color: #1877F2;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.fb span{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.or {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 24px auto;
  width: 410px;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 48%, rgba(204, 204, 204, 1) 48%, rgba(204, 204, 204, 1) 52%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 52%);
}

.or span{
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 0 10px;
}


.enter {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 410px;
  background-color: #f7f7f8;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  filter: drop-shadow(0.5px 0px 0px lightgray)
}

.login {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 410px;
  background-color: #1877F2;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.click {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #00A400;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="fb"><span>facebook</span></h1>
<Form>
  <div class="input">
    <input class="enter" type="text" id="emph" name="emph" placeholder="Mobile number or email address" required>
    <input class="enter" type="password" id='password' name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
  </div>
  <button class="login" type="login">Log in</button>
  <div class="or"><span>or</span></div>
  <button class="click" type="click">Create New Account</button>
</Form>
```

**Note:** Other potential improvements

Instead of adding the width to every element, you could instead add it to the `form` element, and let the child elements take its full width - this means you only need to set the width in one place and it is easier to change.

Also FYI, you also don't need to use `display:flex` at all for this layout - you are creating a standard block layout and using `flex` adds nothing - in might even complicate things later on.

Answer (score 0):

add `.fb{width: fit-content;margin: 0 auto}` to your style to set the width of the `<h1 class="fb">facebook</h1>` and center it.
You can use `::before` & `::after` to display the horizontal lines: try this code:

```
.or{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.or::before, .or::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.75em;
  width: calc(50% - 2em);
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #888888;
  left: 0;
}
.or::after{
  right: 0;
}
```

Change `top: 0.75em` to get the best result.